# Chinese hand fan type topology

Tags: modeling, topology, extrude

I have these faces:

[image]

Now I'd like to add faces in a way that creates the shape of a chinese hand fan:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

This is my attempt with E+S (extrusion and scale), which is wrong:

[image]

Comment: The only thing that looks wrong here is the pivot-point of the scale.. it's at the 3D cursor, which is **not** at the centre of the existing concentric arcs.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a  <kbd>S</kbd> to scale try  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (scale along local normals). Also you need to do it in two separate steps. First:  <kbd>E</kbd> followed by  <kbd>RMB</kbd> (RightMouseButton)  to validate the extrusion but not move the vertices. Then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to scale out your fan shape.

So it is:

- Select the vertices,
- <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> drag mouse outwards and <kbd>LMB</kbd> to validate the scaling.

See gif below:

[image]

Comment: Hi, it seems that this allows me to scale along only one of the normals, but not two of them at the same time. Any ideas? https://imgur.com/a/EkAoGlk

Comment: See my modified answer .

Answer (score 1):

You can create one segment, and use an Array modifier with a rotated empty as an object offset:

[image]

[image]